# How to make line marker circles appear on top of area chart?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I have a dimplejs area chart that works great except for the fact that you sometimes can't hover over data points (line markers) on the bottom area because the top area covers them up. That is, you can see them but they are underneath the top area so the hover event never fires when you mouse over them so the tooltip never appears.

As I understand it, svg z-order is based on order of appearance. I also understand that D3 can be used to reorder elements but not sure if that means it might change the location of the elements or if they could be reordered such that they stay in the same place but are just displayed on top. That would be fantastic, but I'm not even sure how to go about doing it.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this or any other alternative solution appreciated!

Comment: Did you try d3 raise() ?